Can I get access and write data to void**?
I try to allocate memory, and I can't store pointer only one type, so I must store void*, and to access on this pointer void ** pointer.
I try to write, using: *((int *)(void *)):
(value by pointer on void pointer redeployed(interpreted) as integer pointer).
Code examples:
void **d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
 printf("%d\n", sizeof(*( (int *) *d )));

Output:  4
void **d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
*( (int *) *d ) = 1;

Output: segmentation fault (core dumped)

I want to know, if it is possible to access this memory, or how to store data, type of what is unknown.

Why void** instead of void*?

"I can't store pointer only one type" If you need multiple types to be stored at the same location you need to use a union, not a void** or void*.

This code fragments printf 4 because the sizeof operator merely returns the memory size of whatever you pass as argument.
In this case you're basically asking for the size of an int (which is 4 on your platform):
void** d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
printf("%d\n", sizeof(*((int*)*d)));

With this code fragment you get a segmentation fault, because *d points nowhere:
void **d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
*( (int *) *d ) = 1;

You probably want this (no need for double pointers):
void* d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
*((int*)d) = 123;
printf("%d\n", *((int*)d));

Output: 123

thank you, i tried to solve to, solved, checked post, and i got same solution with yours)
but, it doesn't matter, thank you)

I think you are confusing a few things here.

What 'sizeof' is and does.  sizeof is a C compile time operator (not function) that returns the size of the expression passed to it. The operator is processed at compile time and knows nothing about the state of the heap (which is what malloc allocates from at runtime).  If you are expecting your printf to return "10" (the size of the int array you've allocated), you will be disappointed.  C expects you to keep track of what you allocate and stay within the bounds of what you've requested from malloc.

malloc and the C type system.  The malloc function doesn't really care what type your data is, it allocates a block of memory measured in bytes and  expects you to use it correctly.  When it comes to pointers the C type system is mostly there to document intent more than usage.  The void type indicates non-differentiated data and can be useful because it allows you to bypass type checking.  The malloc function returns void* because it can be assigned to any other pointer type (without generating a warning).  If you want an int array you can just declare the variable int*.  You typically don't declare things void*.

Declaring and access (dereferencing) a pointer.  The declaration shows structure, while access (known as dereferencing a pointer) shows usage (there's probably a better way to put that).  So you declared your d variable as "void *", meaning the expected structure is a pointer that points to another pointer (in this case an array which C represents as a pointer).  When you allocate (call malloc) you only get one pointer back.  You defined a structure in terms of two pointers, but only set that variable with one.  Where is your other pointer?  ... It's implied by the array usage.  Consider referring it like this "((int *) d)[0]".  Which casts d as an int* (or array), then uses array notation (pointer offset) to access it.  You can think of the cast as your first pointer and the array reference as your second.


Consider something like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    #define MyArrayCount 10
    #define MyMemorySize sizeof(int) * MyArrayCount
    int* d = malloc(MyMemorySize);
    printf("Array size: %d  memory needed: %ld\n", MyArrayCount, MyMemorySize);
    d[0] = 100;
    d[MyArrayCount - 1] = 9999;    
    printf("[0]=%d  [max]=%d\n", d[0], d[MyArrayCount - 1]);
    
    printf("address as int*:   %p\n", d);
    printf("address as void**: %p\n", (void**) d);    

    return 0;
}

Which will produce output something like this:
Array size: 10  memory needed: 40
[0]=100  [max]=9999
address as int*:   0x5ee63a0792a0
address as void**: 0x5ee63a0792a0

Note, if for some reason you need the memory block addressable via void** you can just cast it to that and it will be the same memory address.


You can access it:

int main()
{
    void **d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    ((int *)d)[5] = 45;
    printf("%d\n", ((int *)d)[5]);
}


sizeof(pointer) only gives the size of pointer itself, not the size of the memory allocated.


It doesn't make sense to use void ** for a pointer to a series of integers. d should be void * in your snippet.

@ikegami did I write that it makes?

Well, yeah. The presumption is that one believe one's own answers make sense.
